# powershell output echo in one line

Tags: powershell, output, echo

Ich have got an array with names called `$arraylist_user`. I run with a for-loop through out the array.
On every loop I output the text

`echo "User:" $arraylist_user[$i] "isn´t in the office!" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\test.txt" -Append -encoding unicode` through a txt-File.

I got every part in a newline.
Like:

```
User:
Tom
isn´t in the office!
```

How can I get the complete sentence `User: Tom isn´t in the office!` in one line in the text file.

I tried:

```
echo -NoNewLine "User:" $arraylist_user[$i] "isn´t in the office!" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\test.txt" -Append -encoding unicode
```

Without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "User: $($arraylist_user[$i]) isn´t in the office!" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\test.txt" -Append -encoding unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

join the strings like

```
"User:", $arraylist_user[$i], "isn´t in the office!" -join " " | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\test.txt" -Append -encoding unicode
```

`"User:", $arraylist_user[$i], "isn´t in the office!" -join " "` will join the three strings `User:`, `$arraylist_user[$i]` and `isn´t in the office!` and add a space between them.